# Inno Setup - Expand function to page

Tags: inno-setup

I would like to be on the site where you can select the installation folder also directly have the choice whether you want to make a start menu entry and desktop icon and leave both page "disappear".
In that case, I have no idea how I can even get offensive...

[image]

Greetings

Comment: Such page does not exist in Inno Setup, you need to modify built-in page which requires a lot of code...

Comment: @Martin Prikryl: Many thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for.